# jquery flot pie left outside border when printting to pdf

Tags: jquery-plugins, flot, wkhtmltopdf, pie-chart

I am using "wkhtmltopdf" in order to print an html report.
This html contains a pie-chart jquery chart.

This html works perfectly fine.

In the other hand the printting seems to go alright buth when i check the ouput pdf the pie charts leaves some kind of circle around the chart. As you may see in the image.

[evidence http://imageshack.com/a/img844/5310/2chv.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img844/5310/2chv.png)

Please,

does somebody knows how to avoid this circle from appering?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not solved it but i got and improvemente by changing the donut chart for a pie chart.

And also by reducing the margins between the sections of the chart.

```
stroke: { color: '#fff', width: 0}
```

[image]